# Blackberry 7 or below clean command using command line

Tags: blackberry, command-line, cordova

Can anybody please tell me how to clean a blackberry 7 project.I am using phonegap and command line in mac for building the project into the device.
For e.g the run command I am using is 
**./cordova/run blackberry**

Phonegap website hasn't given out much details about the clean command.So is there any command for cleaning the project?
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to clean the **simulator**, or clean your build, or both?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the simulator directory. There would be a clean.bat file. Run it. It is a bit slow, but does its work.